# Issues with authentication

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server

I selected the following option in server, but then I can't remote access to my server via RDP.
How to resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any error messages in your client?
Please check the version of your rdp if it is support for NLA.
[image: RDP version]

Comment: And also check to see if you have *permission* to connect.